# SVG mask not clipping in firefox

Tags: css, svg

I have a svg mask made of two dots cutting two holes out of a rectangle. This effect works great in webkit browsers, but in firefox I just get a solid rectangle. Firefox is meant to support svg mask - any ideas where I have gone wrong?

```css
body {background:pink}
#overlay {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 99;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

svg { position:absolute;width: 100%;height:100%}
```

```html
<div id="overlay">

  <svg>

      <mask id="mymask" >
        <rect class="svg-bg" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"/>
        <circle id="hole-1" cx="50%" cy="37vh" r="12vh" fill="#000000"/>
        <circle id="hole-2" cx="50%" cy="63vh" r="12vh" fill="#000000"/>
      </mask>

    <rect id="hole-bg" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"  mask="url(#mymask)"/>

  </svg>

</div>
```

Comment: Firefox does not currently support vh units within SVG. It only supports those units defined in SVG 1.1

Comment: ah thanks so much. Changing the values to % and the mask now work, but the circles do not keep the same distance apart. I guess maybe I need to set them via JS?

Comment: You don't need to set them via JS. You only need to understand the difference between `%` and `vh/vw`. 
Percentage is always relative to the parent, while 'vh/vw' depend on the viewport height or width, respectively. That's why you get the different position of the circles.